# HDD failed, but can PCB replacement fix it?

Tags: hardware, sata, smart, drive-failure, hdd

My WD RED WD80EFAX HDD suddenly died last week: I shut down my Proxmox server, booted it up again and the drive started "clicking". It was clicking for a while, until it stopped and no longer does that. I did not receive any SMART warnings ahead of time, and looking back at the /var/lib/smartmontools/ attrlog, I don’t think there was anything to worry about there:

| date | SMART attribute ID | current | raw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 1 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 2 | 128 | 116 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 3 | 253 | 2031728 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 4 | 99 | 6689 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 5 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 7 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 8 | 128 | 18 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 9 | 95 | 41823 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 10 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 12 | 100 | 2276 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 22 | 100 | 100 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 192 | 93 | 9251 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 193 | 93 | 9251 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 194 | 127 | 279174185011 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 196 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 197 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 198 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-10-24 09:34:51 | 199 | 200 | 0 |

compare that with the first values recorded in that log file:

| date | SMART attribute ID | current | raw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 1 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 2 | 128 | 116 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 3 | 151 | 8617263560 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 4 | 100 | 584 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 5 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 7 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 8 | 128 | 18 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 9 | 96 | 28636 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 10 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 12 | 100 | 557 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 22 | 100 | 100 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 192 | 99 | 1794 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 193 | 99 | 1794 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 194 | 144 | 279174185005 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 196 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 197 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 198 | 100 | 0 |
| 2022-04-15 15:52:32 | 199 | 200 | 0 |

The HDD was connected through an external USB enclosure, so I first tested to make sure the problem persists using another USB enclosure and it does, unfortunately. What I am seeing in dmesg is:

```
[25343.421737] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[25343.442848] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=1561, bcdDevice= 1.04
[25343.442854] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[25343.442857] usb 2-3: Product: SABRENT
[25343.442858] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: SABRENT
[25343.442860] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: DB98765432143
[25343.446053] scsi host1: uas
[25343.446591] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SABRENT                   0104 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[25343.448532] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[25353.377987] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 1953506646 4096-byte logical blocks: (8.00 TB/7.28 TiB)
[25353.378144] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[25353.378147] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[25353.378427] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[25353.378658] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 32768 bytes
[25353.378662] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 268431360 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (32768 bytes)
[25384.996385] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN
[25384.996393] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[25385.016413] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[25385.148590] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[25385.174465] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[25417.783354] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[25417.783528] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD
[25417.783535] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[25417.915763] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[25417.937381] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[25450.530389] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[25450.530552] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD
[25450.530556] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[25450.658774] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[25450.680523] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[25453.039632] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=99s
[25453.039639] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current]
[25453.039641] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[25453.039644] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[25453.039646] I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[25453.039650] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[25483.301277] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN
[25483.301299] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[25483.345279] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[25483.477571] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[25483.499402] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

While the disk appears to report the capacity (7.28 TiB), I cannot get `smartctl` to show anything at all, it gets stuck at `-c`, `-i` and, obviously, `-a`. The disk does, however, "tick" rhythmically and rather quietly during when `smartctl` remains stuck, but it is not the "clicking" sound.

I also tried connecting it via SATA over a borrowed PCI extension card, since my server is a Lenovo Tiny and does not come with a regular SATA connector. There,  I kept getting 'sata link down' errors, although I cannot 100% be sure it wasn’t due to the PCI extension card itself, since I didn’t have another disk to test with it to exclude false negative. I'll see if I can test it again in some other system just to be 100% sure.

Lastly, I removed the PCB and did not see any immediate damage to it. I also cleaned it up a bit, but that didn't do anything.

At this point I am wondering if `smartctl` failing to report anything and the SATA link errors could be indicative of a PCB failure? It would be an odd one, since the disk *does* spin up and partially report itself via USB enclosure, so it's not *completely* broken.

I am slightly confused because I am not sure if I should go through that effort. The replacement PCBs for this model are readily available on Aliexpress at a reasonable price, but it would take quite some work to re-solder the BIOS SMD chip.

P.S. that HDD contained backups only, so nothing critical but I would still prefer to retain the data. And I was also going to set up RAID for it (the main SSD with OS is already RAID1), it just wasn't a priority.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only backup data, my advice is to toss it and get a new one. There is a non-zero chance that the problem, or some of the problem, is not on the PCB, and replacing the PCB is a major endeavor because of the BIOS swap. For both those reasons, PCB replacement could turn out to be wasted effort. An all-new drive should only be a couple hundred dollars, and your time to do the swap is certainly worth more than that.

If you want the practice, buy the PCB, swap the BIOS, and see if it works; but I suspect it won't ever be as trustworthy, reassembled, as a new one would be. For hobby gear, sure, but not for real live (or even backup) data that you care about.

Comment: I actually wouldn't mind practice, didn't think about such approach to the problem before. Even if fixed I would indeed move on to RAID1 right away with a different set of new HDDs, this would only be to recover the data lost.

Answer (score 1):

I worked in a company who offered data recovery services, but I never did this myself. There were other people who disassembled drives, replaced heads and so on. Folks told me there is some calibration data which changes from one to another, and obviously, you will not transfer it to the new PCB.

If PCB is what really broke, this should help you read data and this is actual way they would do it. But don't think the drive will work that way for long, even while you didn't disassembled its mechanical assembly. However, click sounds *hint* at problems with mechanical parts. I'd expect there *are* problems with heads, even though there were no SMART readings that could have been interpreted as early warnings.

Before buying anything, check spring-loaded contacts between PCB and the mechanical part. They can corrode and lose contact. There are cases when, after cleaning those, drive started working flawlessly again and worked for a long time.

Comment: I would have expected that the track calibration data, that is specific to the drive, would be in an ASIC (conceptually a "BIOS chip") on the PCB, hence the requirement for "BIOS" swap. Though of course the calibration ROM might be a separate chip. My concern is that if the problem is in the ASIC, swapping it to the new board might be simply transplanting the problem into new hardware. And OP did say that there has been some board cleanup done, but it was not effective.

Comment: Wrong calibration data will increase amount of seek mismatches and faulty reads (translated to more both correctable and uncorrectable checksum errors) *and faulty writes*, so it will decrease reliability of the drive. The problem O.P. encountered, if in PCB, is likely broken motor power/control path. The drive with replaced PCB should work, but it should be run only once that way, to dump an image to another device. Even if mechanics broke (e.g. head crashed), it is possible to replace *the head* (in a dustless room) and clean, and that what our personnel did (I never did it myself).

Comment: I checked the spring-loaded contacts already, that didn't help, but I should perhaps try again. On another note, why do you suggest that after replacing PCB I should only run it once? In my book, if there were no read errors, and the disk passed some read/write tests, it should be OK?

Comment: Because, as @tsc_chazz correctly noted up there, some chip on the PCB likely contains drive mechanics calibration data that is tuned at a later stage to the particular drive and accounts for some normal mechanical deviations. Other PCB will be tuned to other drive with its own mechanical deviations. And that data will be moved with the PCB. In the result, heads might fly on some other, non-optimal height, and the arm will miss tracks more often, and so on. It should be able to read, but the reliability of the drive reassembled with foreign PCB will be lower than expected. Don't rely on it.